# Probability of drawing different color balls

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

**Question:**
In the urn, we have 4 red, 5 blue, and 6 green balls. We draw two balls consecutively.

**(a)** What is the probability that the drawn balls are of different colors when we return the first drawn ball to the urn?

**(b)** What is the probability that the drawn balls are of different colors when we do not return the first drawn ball to the urn?

**My approach:**
To count them I would make 6 ways of getting different colors.\

**Red+blue, red+green, blue+red, blue+green, green+red and green+blue.**\

So that would be:
$$\frac{4}{15} * \frac{5}{14} + \frac{4}{15} * \frac{6}{14} + \frac{5}{15} * \frac{4}{14} + \frac{5}{15} * \frac{6}{14} + \frac{6}{15} * \frac{4}{14} +\frac{6}{15} * \frac{5}{14}$$

And for the first one it would be same but instead 14 it would be also 15 since we are returning the first ball back.

Is this correct approach?

Comment: there seems to be a typo. Shouldn't the last fraction be $5/14$?

Comment: yes, thanks @Haris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach appears to be correct. But you could make it simpler by consider the complementary event ($E^c$).

Let's find the probability of both the balls being of the same color (assuming we don't return the ball to the urn after the first draw).

The probability of the two balls to be red is

$$P(R) = \frac{4}{15} \times \frac{3}{14}$$

Similarly, for the two balls to be blue (B) or green (G), we have

$$P(B) = \frac{5}{15} \times \frac{4}{14}$$

$$P(G) = \frac{6}{15} \times \frac{5}{14}$$

These events - R, B, and G - are mutually exclusive, so we can add their probabilities to get the probability of their union.

$$ P(E^c) = P(R) + P(B) + P(G)$$

Finally, we subtract from $1$ to get the required probability $P(E)$.

$$P(E) = 1 - P(E^c)$$

Doing all the calculation, the answer would be $74/105$.

---

Even if you don't consider the complement, you can do the following for example.

If the first ball is red, the next must be one of the $11$ that are not red. So,

$$P(R) = \frac{4}{5} \times \frac{11}{14}$$

If you look at your expression above, the first two terms add to the same fraction.

Comment: yes, i was also thinking about this approach, thanks! @Haris

Comment: @peterparker321 you're welcome!